# Understanding the basic inheritance in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails Development and was trying to understand inheritance in Rails, I understood how do a class inherit from a parent class

For Example `MyController < ActionController`,  in this Action Controller is the parent class. But I dont understand this syntax

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

Specifically what is the purpose of **::Base**

Comment: Code tends to be organised into Classes or Modules.  Classes follow inheritance rules, and can be instantiated into instances, whereas modules are more like a simple collection of code.  Sometimes classes are collected into modules to achieve the namespacing Marek refers to:  that is the case here: "ActionController" is a module and "Base" is a class inside that module (the class that your app controllers inherit from).

Comment: thanks a lot Max for providing the detailed information...

Comment: Btw, it's informative to look through the codebase.  have a look in your gems folder for the ActionController module.

Comment: can you please let me know where will this gems folder will be located and in which gem ActionController module is there?

Comment: No I am not using rvm

Comment: ActionController is part of the ActionPack gem.  The gems will be in wherever you installed ruby to: try `echo $GEM_HOME` if in mac/linux.  if you're in windows you should be able to find the folder in your home folder or maybe the C drive, or look for GEM_HOME in your environment variables.

Comment: No, sorry - if you don't know how to find out where your gems folder is then i'm sure you can google it easily enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is used to indicate that `Base` is a class inside of `ActionController` namespace.